# Convert PolygonZ to ordinary Polygon Shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, convert

I'm using QGIS version 2.18.11

When looking in `properties > metadata` of a layer it says `PolygonZ`. I would like it converted to `Polygon` instead so I can merge the PolygonZ shapefile with another. At the moment I generate an error when using `vector > data management tools > merge`...hence if there is an alternative means to merge the two layers which would be easier than converting that would be fine.

Comment: You could use the `Save As...` option, change `Geometry type` to _Polygon_ and make sure the `Include z-dimension` option is unchecked. Or force the geometry type in `Layer Options > SHPT` and set it to _Polygon_ :)

Comment: @James B Follow the same procedure in the above duplicate, but select polygon under geometry instead of point as Joseph explained

Comment: Great stuff, excellent response time as usual. Top marks everyone!